# Why doesn't remix allow inputs of letters in this code?

Tags: string, error

Okay, so this code is actually *designed* to revert when anything but 0, 1, ...9, is entered, but let me explain.

I created this code for general practice.  It may not have practical use, but it's intent is to convert a string version of the digits 0 - 9 to the uint version.  In testing it, it works perfectly when I enter any string with the characters 0 - 9.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ConvertStringToUint {       // This version does not limit the number of bytes in the string to 78.

function stringToUint(string _number) public pure returns(uint) {

    bytes memory strBytes = bytes(_number);

    uint i;
    uint digit;
    uint result;

    for (i = 0; i < strBytes.length; i++) {

        if (strBytes[i] == byte(48))        { 
            digit = 0;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(49)) {
            digit = 1;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(50)) {
            digit = 2;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(51)) {
            digit = 3;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(52)) {
            digit = 4;    
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(53)) {
            digit = 5;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(54)) {
            digit = 6;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(55)) {
            digit = 7;
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(56)) {
            digit = 8;    
        } else if (strBytes[i] == byte(57)) {
            digit = 9;
        } else {
            revert();
        }

        result = result * 10 + digit;

    }
        return result;
}

}
```

However, when I add a letter or any other character, I get an error I didn't expect.

For example, if I enter string "324", it returns the uint "324".  But if I enter string "3a24", I get the error:

> Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2

This suggests that it is not even allowing me to enter these characters as a string in the first place, which I don't understand because the input parameter is a string.

To further test this, I changed the line `else if (strBytes[i] == byte(49))` to `else if (strBytes[i] == byte(97))`, so that now the character "a" will set digit to 0 and the character "0" should cause an error.  Sure enough, entering "0" gives me the error:

> ... VM error: revert.
>   revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.

And even at this point, entering "a" still gives me the error:

> .. Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1

I've been through it several times and can't account for these error differences.  What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Remix, there is a weird, ongoing, bug where you must use quotation marks when you use alpha characters in a string. If the function is expecting a string but you only return numerical characters, it will convert it to a string for you.

So, make sure you are literally typing in `"3a24"` instead of `3a24`.

Your contract will still revert it, based on the code, but at least it would work.